# Robolectric visible() "W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to consume batched input events but the input event receiver has already been disposed."

Tags: android, jenkins, robolectric

We're using `Robolectric` for UnitTests on our SDK, but there's one thing I've noticed which is absolutely cluttering up the logs when we run our test (this is especially an issue on `Jenkins`, when you're running nearly 200 tests).

An example of the start of all our tests is,

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, emulateSdk=21)
public class AppTest {

    private MainActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();
    }
}
```

But when we run over the line,

`activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();`

We get this in our logs,

`18:56:02     W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to consume batched input events but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
18:56:02     W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to consume batched input events but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
18:56:02     W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to consume batched input events but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`

Three lines, over and over, and over again.  The printout happens deep within the `Android` source, in `android.view.InputEventReceiver:consumeBatchedInputEvents`,

```
public final boolean consumeBatchedInputEvents(long frameTimeNanos) {
    if (mReceiverPtr == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Attempted to consume batched input events but the input event "
                + "receiver has already been disposed.");
    } else {
        return nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(mReceiverPtr, frameTimeNanos);
    }
    return false;
}
```

So without finding out how to suppress the logger (which I'd *really* prefer not to do), I'd love to find a way for this not to be hit at the beginning of every test.